# Faulty cooling system but not overheating

Tags: cooling-system, gasket, cylinder-head, air

I've got a Peugeot 2.0L HDI 2003

over the past several months I've had issues with the cooling system, it hasn't overheated until recently but has had other issues.

It first started showing signs of problems when it started losing coolant, I checked all the hoses & anywhere I could think of to find a leak, to no avail (although when I turn on the interior heating I can smell coolant coming through the vents)

The level in the reservoir was forever dropping really low so I would top the coolant up, it also had bubbles coming into it form the small hose at the top of the reservoir. When I open the reservoir it was releasing a large amount of pressure & the level would risae significantly as if there was a blockage in the system. I've ran it like this for some time.

I changed the thermostat & temperature sensor to be on the safe side, then decided after being told it could be the head gasket purchased some Steel Seal (UK head gasket sealer) it's made the coolant very sludgy & dark) ( also did a flush of the system beforehand but don't think half the coolant even came out.

The problem stopped to a point in the sense the coolant level wasn't dropping as much anymore but now it leaks out of the reservoir cap only a small amount & recently it is overheating a little more than normal operating temperature.

I can't afford a large garage bill & just hope I've missed something simple, I forgot to mention that all the pipes are hot so it seems to be going around the system to some degree, I just wonder if it's a blockage or air in the system that won't come out.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated as I say I am on a very low budget

Comment: Where are you located?  Any access to pressure tester kit?     In the USA, Autozone has a tester in their free tool loaner program. ( you pay a 100% refundable deposit only. )With a pressure tester kit you pressurize the cooling system to 10 psi (engine off) then easily and safely look for coolant leaks. It’s possible there is a leak at the heater core inside your instrument panel inside the passenger compartment. If that is the case there should be a small drain at the engine side of the dash panel steel. If it is a heater core leak that’s a pretty tough repairNot for the beginning mechanic.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply, I'm in the UK, no access to pressure tester. one question about a leak to the heater core, wouldn't I get any coolant in the driver / passenger foot well (I don't have any pools of coolant or damp)?

Comment: No if the heater core leaks there is a drain at the bottom of the air handling unit. The drain (which also handles air conditioning condensation) drips at the base of the steel dash panel. You will be able to see the drain from under the car, aft of the engine. It will be on the front passenger seat side of the vehicle.